# Как найти множество чисел кратных 51 по заданной маске?

Tags: python

ЕГЭ информатика 2023

Назовём маской числа последовательность цифр, в которой также могут
встречаться следующие символы:

- символ `"?"` означает ровно одну произвольную цифру;
- символ `"*"` означает любую последовательность цифр произвольной
  длины; в том числе `"*"` может задавать и пустую последовательность.
  Например, маске `123*4?5` соответствуют числа `123405` и `12300425`.

Среди натуральных чисел, не превышающих 10<sup>6</sup>, найдите все числа,
соответствующие маске `12*45*` и делящиеся на число `51` без остатка.

В ответе запишите в первом столбце таблицы все найденные числа в порядке
возрастания, а во втором столбце — соответствующие им частные от
деления на 51.

Моя программа:

```py
for n in range(0,10):
    for i in range(0,10):
        s = '12'+str(n)+'45'+str(i)
        if int(s) % 51 == 0:
            print(s, int(s) / 51)
```

Что она выводит:

```
    122451 2401.0
```

Только одна пара в ответе (обычно в этих задачах 4-6 ответов) или я неправильно понял задачу?

Answer (score 2):

1. Для указанной маски `12*45*` следует определить минимальное и максимальное числа.
   Минимумом явно будет число `1245`, максимумом соответственно `129945` (а не `1'000'000`)
2. Для начального значения цикла следует подобрать ближайшее кратное 51, затем в цикле использовать шаг 51 для проверки только кратных чисел
3. Для проверки маски можно использовать регулярное выражение `"12\d*45\d*"` в функции `re.match`

```py
import re

n = 1245
if n % 51 != 0:
    n += 51 - n % 51 

m = min(129946, 1000000)

for i in range(n, m, 51):
    if (re.match("12\d*45\d*", str(i))):
        print (i, i // 51)
```

Результат:

```
122145 2395
122451 2401
124542 2442
124593 2443
127245 2495
```

Answer (score 2):

Ещё один вариант решения "в лоб", без оптимизации:

```py
for x in [''] + list(map(str, range(100))):
    for y in [''] + list(map(str, range(100))):
        s = '12' + x + '45' + y
        if len(s) <= 6 and int(s) % 51 == 0:
            print(s, int(s) // 51)
```

Просто перебираем в качестве первого фрагмента пустое место и числа от 0 до 99 и тоже самое для второго фрагмента.

```
124542 2442
124593 2443
122451 2401
122145 2395
127245 2495
```

Comment: Для полноты данных нужно будет в список входных строк добавить строки с ведущим нулём `"00", "01",..."09"`, и сгенерировать полный список один раз.

Answer (score -2):

Доработал программу и все получилось)[image: python]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Здесь также не проверяется вариант строк с ведущим нулем.  Для целочисленного деления следует использовать оператор `//`